# vuejs route between components scroll same

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-component

```html
<template>
    <div class="index">
        <common-header id="common-header" class="common-header" v-el:commonheader></common-header>
        <router-view transition keep-alive class="index-view"></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

the route view will show two component A and B, while component A scrollTop is 0, I route to component B, and scroll down, and then route to component A, A is also scroll. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have try set router options saveScrollPosition, but the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a global before hook to the router, which will be called before every route transition starts and scroll to the top of the page. That is how I have solved it. Read [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/1.0/docs/en/api/before-each.md)

Vue 1.

```
router.beforeEach(function (transition) {
 window.scrollTo(0, 0)
 transition.next()
})
```

For Vue2:

```
 const router = new VueRouter({
   scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
     return { x: 0, y: 0 }
   }
 })
```

Refer [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html?q=)

Comment: link not found now

Answer (score 0):

For **Vuejs2.0**, there is a new accepted way dealing with scroll behavior on page changes:

```
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
 const router = new VueRouter({
     scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
         return { x: 0, y: 0 }
     }
 })
```

This will scroll to the top of the page after each navigation change. You can [read up on the full, official documentation about this functionality here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are scroll the wrong element.I have make the same mistake like that:component A and component B is both in element Body,and I make the body scroll,so as long as you move the scroll bar,it will work for both A&B.I finally work out it by scrolling component instead of scrolling the body.